# onclick link with dropdown menu behavior in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, onclick

I have an HTML document with a navbar menu. One of the items on the menu has a dropdown menu that has clickable links. Everything works fine in Chrome and IE, but in Firefox the links in the dropdown links have trouble.

Here is the code. I tried to keep only relevant parts, so hopefully I didn't accidentally delete anything important:

```css
   #menu-items {
     height: 100%;
     display: inline-block;
     white-space: nowrap;
   }
   
   #menu-items li {
     height: 100%;
     vertical-align: middle;
     text-align: center;
     display: inline-block;
     float: left;
   }
   
   #menu-items a {
     text-decoration: none;
   }
   
   .dropdown {
     position: relative;
     display: inline-block;
   }
   
   .dropdown-content {
     display: none;
     z-index: 1;
     position: absolute;
     top: 10px;
     left: 10px;
   }
   
   .dropdown-content a {
     padding-left: 11px;
     padding-right: 9px;
     text-decoration: none;
     display: block;
   }
   
   .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
     display: block;
   }
```

```html
<div id="nav-bar">
  <div id="menu">
    <div id="menu-items">

      <a href="item_1.html">
        <li>item_1</li>
      </a>
      <li class="dropdown" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="window.location='item_2.html';">
        <div class="dropdown"><a href="item_2.html">item_2</a>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="item_2a.html">item_2a</a>
            <a href="item_2b.html">item_2b</a>
            <a href="item_2c.html">item_2c</a>
            <a href="item_2d.html">item_2d</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <a href="item_3.html">
        <li>item_3</li>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the HTML code, the `onclick="window.location='item_2.html';"` is there because I want the whole box in that navbar menu item clickable, rather than just the text inside of it - this is the only way I have found to make this occur - I have tried, for example, putting the anchor tags on the outside of that list item, as well as several other solutions which I can't recall right now. However, the `onclick` solution seems to make it so that the links in the dropdown menu all lead to `item_2.html`, rather than `item_2a.html`, etc. Again, this is a problem in Firefox only.

Does anyone know a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution. I added some inline javascript to the `<div class="dropdown-content">` containing the `stopPropagation()` function. The HTML now reads as:

```
<div id="nav-bar">
  <div id="menu">
    <div id="menu-items">

      <a href="item_1.html">
        <li>item_1</li>
      </a>
      <li class="dropdown" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="window.location='item_2.html';">
        <div class="dropdown"><a href="item_2.html">item_2</a>
          <!--HERE'S THE CHANGE-->
          <div class="dropdown-content" onclick="(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); })(event)">
            <a href="item_2a.html">item_2a</a>
            <a href="item_2b.html">item_2b</a>
            <a href="item_2c.html">item_2c</a>
            <a href="item_2d.html">item_2d</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <a href="item_3.html">
        <li>item_3</li>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tested it briefly in Chrome, IE, and Firefox, it worked in all 3, so that seemed to do the trick.